# Enable the Submit button if form values changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a piece of jquery code which checks if input fields changed in the form and then unable the submit button, However, it is not working on Input type=File, If I select the file, the button remains disabled. Any Help would be appreciated?
Here is the jquery code

```
 $('form')
        .each(function(){
            $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize())
        })
        .on('change input', function(){
            $(this)
                .find('input:submit, button:submit')
                .attr('disabled', $(this).serialize() == $(this).data('serialized'))
            ;
        })
        .find('input:submit, button:submit')
        .attr('disabled', true)
    ;
```

Comment: Should `on('change input',` not be `on('change', 'input',`?

Comment: I tried this too but it didn't work.My code is working fine except for input type file, for all the other input types it is working perfectly.

Comment: You can't serialize a `file` input.

Comment: Then what's the solution? My code is above, can you please modify that? I am not that good with Jquery or Javascript

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` doesn't work for file inputs. You can get the input's filename and save that instead.

```
function mySerialize(obj) {
    if (obj.type == 'file') {
        return obj.files[0] ? obj.files[0].name : '';
    } else {
        return $(obj).serialize();
    }
}

$('form')
    .each(function(){
        $(this).data('serialized', mySerialize(this));
    })
        .on('change input', function(){
            $(this)
                .find('input:submit, button:submit')
                .attr('disabled', mySerialize(this) == $(this).data('serialized'))
            ;
        })
    .find('input:submit, button:submit')
    .attr('disabled', true)
;
```

This assumes single file inputs. If you have multi-file inputs you'll need to loop over all the files in `mySerialize()` and concatenate them instead of just using `files[0]`.

Comment: But how do I enable the button if the user selects the file?

Comment: What I am looking for is, if the user enters anything in input type or selects any file then the button will get enabled. My code is running fine for all the input types except file I just want to check if user selects any image then the button will get enabled.
That's it.

Comment: I thought you're trying to detect if he changed the value from the previous value. If you just want to detect if an input is filled in, you don't need any of the `.data()` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
   $('form')
    .each(function(){
        $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize())
    })
    .on('change input', function(){ 

        var changed = false;
        var fInputs = $(":file");

        for (var i=0; i<fInputs.length; i++) {
            changed = (fInputs[i].files.length) ? true : changed;
        }

        changed = ($(this).serialize() !== $(this).data('serialized')) ? true : changed;

        $(this)
            .find('input:submit, button:submit')
            .attr('disabled', !changed)
        ;
    })
    .find('input:submit, button:submit')
    .attr('disabled', true);
```